# Do I need to remove ferrule from shutoff valve pipe

Tags: plumbing

Is it possible to use the same ferrule /compression ring that my current shutoff valve uses for the new quarter turn angle stop valve?

Comment: Usually not recommended unless no choice.  You take a much greater chance of a leak happening.

Comment: Thank you @crip659 - I meant to say replace not remove hehe.   But I hope it doesn’t need to be replaced.   Such a hassle pulling the ferrule.

Answer (score 1):

That sometimes works. Be prepared to pull/replace the ferrule and possibly cut back the pipe if necessary.

Comment: Thank you @kreemoweet - it was a crazy day today.  I initially tried to do compression fitting but anyway I did remove the original compression nut and ring (ferrule),  but when I installed the compression fitting angle valve it  was leaking like crazy.  I also bought a Sharkbite angle valve fitting as well, and it worked !  No leaks!   Just need to push in the fitting to the 1-inch mark on the pipe (I used a marker) to ensure proper install.  Am a new fan of Sharkbite.